# How correctly address to specific column in Cursor?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

Lets assume, that we have some 2 tables in SQLite: `TBL_PRODUCT` and `TBL_PRODUCT_ALIASES`. Now, I want to query some data from joined two tables:

```
String sql = "SELECT " + TBL_PRODUCT + "." + C_PROD_PKEY_ID + ", " + TBL_PRODUCT_ALIASES + "." + C_PROD_ALIASES_PKEY_ID +
    " FROM " + TBL_PRODUCT + " LEFT JOIN " + TBL_PRODUCT_ALIASES + " ON " + TBL_PRODUCT + "." + C_PROD_PKEY_ID + " = " + TBL_PRODUCT_ALIASES + "." + C_PROD_ALIASES_PKEY_ID +
    " WHERE " + C_PROD_SERVER_ID + " = ? LIMIT 1";

Cursor cursor = SQLiteDataHelper.getInstance().rawQuery(sql, new String[] {"" + js_CartProduct.getLong("prod_id")});
```

Thats works great without any problem. And then I want to acquire some data from the returned cursor:

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Long prodId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TBL_PRODUCT + "." + C_PROD_PKEY_ID));
    //... Some other code
}
```

Now, here is the problem: `C_PROD_PKEY_ID` and `C_PROD_ALIASES_PKEY_ID` are in the real world the same Strings: `"_id"`. And as the result `getLong()` returns long not from the needed column of `cursor`.

How should I correctly address to the needed column? Are there other methods besides using `AS` in sql query OR/AND using definite numbers in `cursor.getLong(0)` instead of `cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TBL_PRODUCT + "." + C_PROD_PKEY_ID))`?

**Update:**

`cursor.getColumnNames()` returns this: `[_id, _id]`.

Comment: can you ask the cursor for the list of the column names and post it ?

Comment: @njzk2 done, please see modified question.

Comment: how about if you use AS ? like "select " + TBL_PRODUCT + "." + C_PROD_PKEY_ID + " as foo" ?

Comment: this is working, yes. But I am asking if there are other methods.

Comment: sorry, didn't see you tried this already. I don't know any other method, actually

Comment: to my knowledge, no there isn't. use @njzk2 advice. user "AS".